# How to reduce lenght of value from JSON using JQ

Tags: json, jq

Sorry for wrong title. I cant find better title. I have json like this:

```
[
  {
    "id": "35a97c36397886b93bd5619f38c676e739f7f834f82838dcfed602da1d3abf74",
    "name": "this is title one"
  },
  {
    "id": "a547d0112840946aa9e5c266261888d6ab7706e69fc7bb7fdbf907ea2d3da735",
    "name": "this is title two"
  }
]
```

I want modify using jq and give output like this. I only pick 8 characthers from ID:

```
[
  {
    "id": "35a97c36",
    "name": "this is title one"
  },
  {
    "id": "a547d011",
    "name": "this is title two"
  }
]
```

Really appreciate for any help.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [Array/String Slice operator](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Array/StringSlice:.%5B10:15%5D)

```
jq 'map(.id |= .[:8])'
```

- Where `[:8]` means; take char `0` to `8`.
- If you don't want to start from index `0`, use eg: `.[3:8]`

---

The above command will produce:

```json
[
  {
    "id": "35a97c36",
    "name": "this is title one"
  },
  {
    "id": "a547d011",
    "name": "this is title two"
  }
]
```

##### [JqPlay Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/pBwkHnY2su)

Comment: Hi, that work for me. Thank you.
sorry for my lack understanding using proper jq docs.